# Question about ring of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a commutative and unitary ring. Let $S$ be a set and suppose that $S = X \cup Y$ with $X$ and $Y$ disjoint.
If $x_1,...,x_m\in X$ and $y_1,...,y_m\in Y$.

I have this question
$z=y_1+x_1-y_1\in A[S]$ but it is not true that $z\in A[X]$?

Comment: Do you similarly think $1/2-1/2\not\in\Bbb Z?\,$ It seems you are confusing (polynomial) ground terms (unevaluated expressions) with their values. The term $\, t = y_1+x_1-y_1$ is not in $A[S]$ but its value obtained by evaluating the ring operations yields $\,x_1\in A[X].\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true that $z \in A[x]$, because addition in $A$ is commutative, which implies that addition in any $A$-module is commutative. (In general a module over *any* ring will always be an abelian group (where the group operation is addition)). So $y_1 + x_1 - y_1 = x_1 \in A[x]$.

Comment: But $z$ is defined in $A[X]$?. I mean, it seems to me that it doesn't make sense for $y_1$ or $-y_1$ to be mentioned in A[X], since both elements belong to $Y$ or $A[Y]$, not $A$ or $A[X]$.

Comment: @ops, you can mention all you want in $A[S]$, but since $z=x_1$ it follows that $z\in A[X]$.

Comment: @ops You're looking at $A[X]$ as a submodule of $A[S]$. In this case $z = x_1$ is a specific element in $A[S]$ that is also a part of the submodule $A[X]$.